# Codigo de error ORA00904

Tags: sql, oracle

me genera el error de indentificador no válido cuando trato de crear una tabla con llaves foráneas, adjunto evidencia[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
CREATE TABLE Expediente_enfermera(

Codigo_expenf NUMBER PRIMARY KEY ,
nombre_paciente VARCHAR2(60),
apellido_paciente VARCHAR2(60),
edad INT
);

CREATE TABLE Expediente_doctor(
Codigo_expdoc NUMBER ,
Sintomas VARCHAR2(300),
observaciones VARCHAR2(500),
Tratamiento VARCHAR2(500),
value number,
CONSTRAINT pk_expdoc
PRIMARY KEY (Codigo_expdoc),
CONSTRAINT fk_Expenf
FOREIGN KEY (Codigo_expenf)
REFERENCES Expediente_enfermera(Codigo_expenf)
);

CREATE TABLE Expediente_paciente(
Codigo_exppac NUMBER,
value number,
CONSTRAINT pk_exppac
PRIMARY KEY (Codigo_exppac),
CONSTRAINT fk_expdoc 
FOREIGN KEY (Codigo_expdoc)
REFERENCES Expediente_doctor(Codigo_expdoc)
);
```

Comment: El código se comparte como imagen. Pa los viejales como yo que revisamos SO desde un móvil, ver las imágenes es imposible. Y pa los que quieren replicar tu error, pues es ponerlos a transcribir. De paso, ajustas el título porque parece que el código de error es diferente

Comment: gracias hermano, pondré el código de ahora en adelante, perdon por eso

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y mejora tu pregunta. Como te han mencionado, no todos pueden ver las imágenes correctamente, mucho menos se puede hacer _copypaste_ de ellas.

Answer (score 0):

No tienes la columna `codigo_Expenf` en la tabla `Expediente_doctor`. Tienes que agregar esa columna a la tabla o eliminar la llave foránea.

Comment: Complemento de esta respuesta: la foreign key explícita indica qué campo de la tabla refiere a una PK de otra tabla. Declarar la Foreign key no crea automágicamente el campo, hay que declararlo explícitamente junto a las demás columnas.